# Can rmdir be used recursively?

Tags: unix, pipe, rmdir

The manpage only gives these options:

```
      --ignore-fail-on-non-empty
                  ignore each failure that is solely because a directory
                  is non-empty
  -p, --parents   Remove DIRECTORY and its ancestors.  E.g., `rmdir -p a/b/c' is
                  similar to `rmdir a/b/c a/b a'.
  -v, --verbose   output a diagnostic for every directory processed
      --help     display this help and exit
      --version  output version information and exit
```

How would I pipe a `find` or `ls` to recursively delete all empty directories in a file tree?

Comment: please see this: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/8430/how-to-remove-all-empty-directories-in-a-subtree

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
find . -type d -empty -delete
```

Like all destructive commands, print and sanity check the targets (omit the `-delete`) before executing the full command.